# audio engine on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to develop a voip application for iPhone. Could you let me know how can I achieve a good voice quality? How should I start with developing a good audio engine for iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know enough that you need to answer this question, I would start elsewhere. VoIP is a tricky area.

If you have to do it (i.e. this is your job and you have no choice), I would start with some open source voice audio codecs such as [speex](http://www.speex.org/). You could either port it to iPhone or, use it to learn from.